# How to number items in a Xamarin.Forms ListView using the index of each item in the ItemsSource, including when the items are removed?

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a converter which takes in the ListView as a parameter to for each item as the List, and then, using the ItemsSource and IndexOf, I can determine the items position in the list and return that as a number for the View:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter, IMarkupExtension
{
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         var listView = parameter as ListView;
         var collection = listView.ItemsSource as IList;
         object item = value;

         var answer = collection.Count - collection.IndexOf(item); //I'm actually numbering items in reverse.
         return answer;
     }
}
```

I bind to it using the entire binding context ( `{Binding .}` ) so that each item is passed as a value to it's own converter, like so:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewItself" ItemsSource="{Binding TheItemSource}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding ., Converter={converters:MyConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference ListViewItself}}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This works very well. As I add items to my list, the converter correctly calculates the right item place.

My issue now, is that when I remove items from the collection and the ListView, the values for each remaining item in the ListView should automatically update, so as to take into account their new positions. But this is not the case. The converters are called, but with many null values for the items.

I want to know, how can I call RaisePropertyChanged for each binding context in the list so that the converter fires properly for all of them?

**Edit:**
I try to use 
`RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TheItemSource))` when I remove an item from the collection, but it doesn't fire the converter for each item like I'd expect.

Comment: One ugly/quick way could be firing that the entire list changed (which kind of did)

Comment: Why exactly do you need a converter to number your listview items in the first place? Then you are passing a reference of the whole listview, don't you think this is too much overhead?

Comment: I agree @G.hakim. It did seem like a convenient way to avoid renumbering every time items are added and removed. Wouldn't this lead to a large overhead as well for O(n)?

Comment: Actually if you are using the NotifyPropertyChanged with a single method i would say not as much as an overhead as your solution is